# Cant boot to Windows XP but can boot to everything else

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot

I have an Optiplex gx270 I mainly use for messing around with networking.  I had Ubuntu Installed on it, but decided to re-install XP.  The install of XP goes good, the computer restarts and hangs when on the XP splash screen.  Eventually it loaded the windows first time setup and after 20 hours it finished.

After that it would hang on the splash screen for an hour and finally go to the desktop.  Once there everything was insanely slow.  So after formatting and installing windows a few more times with different disk still had the same problem.  I noticed it also ran slow if I booted to a flash drive or cd.  I removed all non-essential hardware, removed all ram and tested each stick 1 at a time in each port.  Ran memtest for 24 hours, ran diagnostics on the harddrive, checked to make sure the motherboard was not shorting out, check the caps on the mother board, reseated everything, and tested the power supply.  After testing the power supply the computer would not boot, replaced the CMOS battery and that fixed it from not booting and running slow from booting to other devices but still had the problem of it hanging on the windows splash screen.  Also in the process I put new thermal paste on the processor.

So I decided to install windows 7 to see how that worked.  It installed, and runs perfectly (as good as it can on a 2.8ghz P4 with a gig of ram).  Any one have any ideas on what would cause this problem just with XP?

EDIT: hard-drive not making any noises and seems to be spinning just fine.

Comment: Oh man, I've replaced so many capacitors on the GX270s.... I had a contract with a local school system that had 50 of them, and after *their* deal with Dell expired in 2008, they wanted to get a few more years out of machines.  So, that's where I came in.... replacing bad Caps till they replaced the machines.  With a GX270, the FIRST thing you gotta check, are the Caps http://news.cnet.com/PCs-plagued-by-bad-capacitors/2100-1041_3-5942647.html

Comment: I might be a faulty driver. Can you boot in safe mode to xp?

Comment: I looked for bad caps and didnt see any but ill go over it again.  You know I don't think I ever tried to boot to safe mode, I know I did when it first tried to go to windows setup but couldnt because it hadnt gone through the setup yet...I might try to reinstall windows xp again and test it out.

Comment: Do you have any extra hardware installed? Or just the bare optiplex with RAM, HDD and DVD?

Comment: Lol not even a DVD drive just a CD drive, but yeah everything is bare except for an Nvidia 5200fx, which I have tried it with and without.

Comment: Other OSs run fine so I keep returning to non-hardware problems. E.g. some BIOS config option which gets triggered in XP but not in an other OS. Are there any iInterupt storms if you boot an other OS (e.g. via a live CD).  Does changing the ACPI config settings help (E.g. plug and play OS settings)?

Comment: If Windows 7 works shouldn't you just use that? I mean its a more secure operating system and will run everything you need and you have XP Mode for everything that doesn't. Just enable the classical look and it will get rid of Aero.

Comment: @Ramhound that requires a license for win7. Not that expensive, but using XP is a lot cheaper since the Dell probably came with one.

Comment: Exactly I have the OEM XP Pro disk and I don't use this pc for anything other then testing and messing around with.

@Ramhound even with everything disabled win7 still runs slowly it ran perfectly on ubuntu 11.10 with standard gnome...i could even play minecraft on it.  But XP also ran fine before putting on ubuntu.

Comment: @Hennes thats kind of what Im thinking I used the jumper to reset the BIOS, I cant remember if they even had ACPI options in it, I'm at work right now so ill have to check it once I get home but i know the bios options were very limited.

Comment: Nods. I worked with loads of optiplex GX240 and 260, one or two 270 and a hundred GX280.  In my mind they all blend, even though the later models had more options.

Comment: @Hennes and for your other part of your question yeah running from a bootable flashdrive with puppy linux works just fine.  But like jmreicha said in the comments on his answer, everything I have been doing has been from a flash drive...maybe there is something wrong with the cd-drive.  Just another thing to test out.

Comment: May be a problem with your XP installation image? Try other CD or image for boot.

Comment: @avirk I've tried 2 different disk.  Both of them don't have any visible scratches.  I also built a UBCD4win iso from one of them, so it should be fine.

Comment: Then I will recommend you to backup your data and delete all the partition on hard drive and then recreate them and install the XP from scratch.

Comment: @avirk this has been done multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I'll take a stab at this one.  I **ALWAYS** like to test all of the components (RAM, HD, Power, bad caps, etc.) before anything else in situations like this just because it saves so much time and effort later on down the road.  The advice Bon Gart gave is very good as well in these types of scenarios.

Even if the reinstall worked and things are working now, doesn't give you much of a guarantee on anything.  Basically, this set of steps is a good way of covering your bases so you aren't banging your head into a wall later on.

There are a variety of bootable disk utilities you can use to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

Another simple thing to test for would be faulty RAM, with something like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: User has already mentioned in his post that he already tried those things. So you should have to come out with new/fresh idea for the use. :)

Comment: Like I said in my question I have already ran diagnostics on the hard drive and ran memtest for 24 hours with no errors.  Also removed all of the ram and tested them one by one in each slot.

Comment: Sorry it is apparently still too early for me :P  Have you checked the XP installation media for defects, scratches, etc.

Comment: @jmreicha Yep the OEM XP Pro disk is just fine, I also used a second XP Home disk I had same issue with both.

Comment: What about swapping out the optical drive or booting from an external optical drive?

Comment: That I have not tried either....I can try to install XP from a flash drive since I ran out of spare optical drives.  Since it only has a cd-rom drive I installed windows 7 and ubuntu from my flash drive...that could be it!

Comment: Also, how did you test your power?  If you haven't, you might try swapping for a known good power suppply.

Comment: I used a power supply tester and plugged in a good power supply.

Comment: Ok that's good.  Let us know if the USB XP install works!

Comment: Forgot to update this but removed the cd drive after I installed windows 7 and now windows 7 runs great on it!  Something went terribly wrong with that cd drive.